# SSRS - Dataset(s) order of execution

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, execution

I have a report that runs a Stored Procedure in Oracle.  This procedure fills several tables with data in Oracle.  I then want to query those tables and load several Tablix(s) in my SSRS report.  I need the Stored Proc to run first.  How can I ensure the Stored Proc runs before the DataSet queries that I use to fill the Tablix(s)?

Comment: I answered my own Question...see below